# CytoscapeJs - full Neighborhood

Tags: cytoscape.js

When using the `neighborhood()`, Cytoscape only provides the direct surrounding nodes.

Is there a built in option to receive the full neighborhood / connected nodes as well? The docs don't specify anything around the neighborhood section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this as workaround

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', (e) => {
  const selected = e.target;
  const predecessors = selected.predecessors();
  const successors = selected.successors();
  ...
});
```